# Get JasperReport object from org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I'm using Spring MVC 3 + JasperReports integration to generate a downloadable PDF file when the Controller sends the response back to the client.
What I need to do now is to send the generated PDF file by E-Mail through a CronJob instead, so I can't use the ModelAndView approach.

I was thinking in re-using the JasperReportsPdfView bean defined in the jasper-views.xml file to retrieve the JasperReport object, fill it and then export it using the JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream() method. 
Does anybody know if I'm following the right approach or is it there any better way of doing this?

Thank you.